# Trigger Azure logic app when row is inserted

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have created Azure logic app. It's aim is to send an email and SMS each time when record is inserted to a table in Azure SQL database. I can see that many records are inserted into this table (I use Azure functions to populate it). Could you let me know what I have done wrong?

[image]

Comment: Could you please click on `Overview -> Runs history` and give us a screenshot of the execution result of the logic app? [Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kgPG.png). This helps us reproduce your problem.

Comment: From the runs history, I want to confirm weather the trigger is not triggered at all.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your `temperature_events` table contains an identity column as required by the [SQL Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/)

> 5. When invoking triggers, we have the following limitations:
>
>    - A ROWVERSION column is required for OnUpdatedItems
>    - An IDENTITY column is required for OnNewItems